# How to render values of an array containing strings or any other basic type using JsRender

Tags: json, templates, jsrender

Using [JsRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender), I'm trying to render out the values of an array full of strings, and they're coming out as blank. I've tried {{:$value}}, {{:$data}}, {{:value}} and {{:data}} and none of them work. What is the syntax to do this?

**Template:**

```
<script id="tmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
  {{:author}} wrote these books:<br/>
  {{for books}}
    book=<span>{{:$data}}{{:$value}}{{:data}}{{:value}}</span>
  {{/for}}
  <br/><br/>
</script>
```

**JS:**

```
var data = [
  { author: "John", books: [ "j1","j2","j3" ]},
  { author: "Sarah", books: [ "s1","s2","s3" ]}
];

var tmpl = $.templates("#tmpl");
var html = tmpl.render(data);
$("div").html(html);
```

It's rendering...

```
John wrote these books:
book= book= book= 

Sarah wrote these books:
book= book= book=
```

Live example here: http://jsbin.com/kutude/1/edit?html,js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, you can write:

```
{{for books}}<span>{{:#data}}</span>{{/for}}
```

But alternatively you can simply write:

```
{{for books}}<span>{{:}}</span>{{/for}}
```

Since `{{:xxx}}` defaults to the current data item, so you can access it either with no parameter, or with the parameter `#data`

Answer (score 0):

It's `{{:#data}}` ! Update: `{{for books}}<span>{{:#data}}</span>{{/for}}`